# Python - A Requests library newbie

Tags: python, session, python-requests, posting

this is my first post on those  forums and hopefully you'll understand that, i am a programming newbie as well. 
So, i want to do my first project in Python using the requests library about something that i'm quite passionate about. It's an osu! map downloader in which you will be able to download maps through a command line. First of all, i am learning the requests library to get access to the website (login). 
This is my code so far:

```
import requests
import time

inUserName = input("Nickname: ")
inUserPass = input("Password: ")
req = requests.get("http://osu.ppy.sh/p/api")

from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
requests.get("https://osu.ppy.sh/forum/ucp.php?mode=login", auth=HTTPBasicAuth(inUserName, inUserPass))

with requests.Session() as session:
       POSTrequest = session.post(url=req, data={'username': inUserName, 'password': inUserPass})

time.sleep(2)
```

I'm geting Response 200 from this, which is great.. but when a few months ago i've used a similar code i got some HTML which wasn't helpful either, i knew that i wasn't getting connected in any way.

The error is:

```
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '<Response [200]>': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://<Response [200]>?
```

Any help in improving the code would be appreciated, thanks very much and sorry for any English mistakes i've made, not the first language.

Comment: Please can you provide the full traceback of the error, rather than just the last line? Or is this the output from `print(POSTrequests.txt)`? I'm a bit unclear where this is coming from :)

Comment: This doesn't seem correct:

    `req = requests.get("http://osu.ppy.sh/p/api")
    
    .
    .

    with requests.Session() as session:
           POSTrequest = session.post(url=req, data={'username': inUserName, 'password': inUserPass})`

Why are you using the response of the GET request to `http://osu.ppy.sh/p/api` as the url of the `post` request?  What does `print(req)` print?

Comment: `Nickname: 1
Password: 1
<Response [200]>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Windows Path", line 20, in <module>
    POSTrequest = session.post(url=req, data={'username': inUserName, 'password': inUserPass})`

Comment: And i've also got 3 of those like that, they are very similar, and then the error. And also, yeah.. it should be .text, gonna change it now.

Comment: print(req) was supposed to be used for experimental purposes, just to see what it's going to give me.

Comment: And yes, you are right. I should give the url of the login page for the GET request.

Comment: I've changed the code now, so it might make more sense.

Comment: Right, so the error in the question is the result of `session.post(url=req,` where you pass a get request result instead of the URL? And what you posted in the comments is from what exactly? From `print(req)`?

Comment: @roganjosh Thank you for pointing out the error. 
I don't understand your second point, sorry.
I was responding to DeepSpace's comments.

Comment: Ok, ignore the second part for now. What happens when you change `url=req` to `url = "http://osu.ppy.sh/p/api"` (or something similar)? Because that probably explains the error written in your actual question.

Comment: Though it it kind of weird. Because i want to get requests from osu's api, then i want to get requests from the login page of osu and authenticate it with the Nick and Pass.

Comment: @roganjosh thanks, that outputted a completely error. A NameError: 'PostRequests' are not defined'. I will be back in a few minutes.

Comment: Because it's not called `POSTrequests`, it's called `POSTrequest` without the "s", so `if POSTrequests.status_code == 200:` will give you `NameError`

Comment: Now that i fixed the errors, i get no errors. Thanks very much! Now i just need to know that i connected to the website somehow!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've specified the `url` for one of your posts improperly.

```
import requests
import time

inUserName = input("Nickname: ")
inUserPass = input("Password: ")
osuApiUrl = "http://osu.ppy.sh/p/api"
session = requests.Session()
req = session.get(osuApiUrl)


session.get("https://osu.ppy.sh/forum/ucp.php?mode=login", auth=(inUserName, inUserPass))

POSTrequest = session.post(url=osuApiUrl, data={'username': inUserName, 'password': inUserPass})

if POSTrequests.status_code == 200:
    print(POSTrequests.text)
    print(r.status_code)
time.sleep(2)
```

Further, if any cookies are set by the server, you should be using a session for the entire script. By using the functional API, you're creating and discarding a session for each request. This is much more efficient.

Comment: Thank you, though i don't understand the second part with the functional API. How do i make it more efficient?

Comment: @Nathan it's already been done for you. Notice that `session = requests.Session()` is now at the top i.e. create the session once and keep using that session. Otherwise you're wasting time creating and destroying the sessions, which defeats the purpose of that feature.

Comment: Very minor point, but based on the discussion in the comments, `if POSTrequests.status_code == 200:` will fail because its actual name is `POSTRequest`, singular, in the line above.

Comment: Thank you! I got rid of the Status code, now i just need to know if i connected to the website or not.